# MySQL Diacritics insensitive search

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a Romanian dictionary database. The word table has a column named `Word` which is `utf8_romanian_ci` collation. In this column I keep all the words. Most of the Romanian words have diacritics: *acasă*, *mâine* ...etc.

I try to run a query which ignores the diacritics. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM WordList where Word = 'acasa'
```

should return  the word *acasă*

I tried:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

before the query, but it does not work.

I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM WordList where Word = 'acasa' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

It does not work either.

Any idea that it might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` to query:

```
SELECT *
FROM WordList
WHERE Word = _utf8 'acasa' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Test on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c40d1/8)

*More info:*

- [MySQL: Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)
- [MySQL: Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html)

Comment: It does not work. It gets me the following message: `COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' `

Comment: Add charset `_utf8`; see modified answer.

Comment: Is it normal to work much slower? My table has around 200.000 records and I join a table with 400.000 definitions... Query took 5.9184 sec (without UTF I had 0.0175 sec)

Comment: To run faster `Word` column must have the same collation what is used in the query, and must be indexed. So if it's possible change `Word` column collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` in the database.

Comment: in this case would the `Word` column still keep my diacritics (ăîțșâ)

Comment: Yes, because you use `utf-8` character set. A collation defines only how characters are compared (and indexed) but not how they are stored in the table.